# Updating viewstate from postback response

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, postback, viewstate

I have ASP.NET site. At one point postback is triggered and some data is modified on server and response is sent (with new view state).
Problem is that I use jQuery to show only a portion of that response on page. That works, but I'm having problems updating view state with new value.
I have somethig like this:

```
var updatePreviewArea = function (nid) {
    var $content = jQuery('<div></div>');
    $content.load('http://site.com?nid=' + nid, function (response) {
        var $response = jQuery(response);

        jQuery('targetDiv1').replaceWith($response.find('#srcDiv1'));
        jQuery('targetDiv2').replaceWith($response.find('#srcDiv2'));

        // update viewstate from postback response
        var selectors = ['#__VIEWSTATE', '#__EVENTVALIDATION'];
        for (var i in selectors) {
            var value = $response.find(selectors[i]).val();
            jQuery(selectors[i]).val(value);
        }
    });
}
```

But after this I get:

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Validation of
>   viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or
>   cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same
>   validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in
>   a cluster.' when calling method: [nsIDOMEventListener::handleEvent]

Comment: Is the page you're loading with jQuery the same as the original page? Do you have a Web farm?

Comment: It is not the same page and it is not a farm (but I have set the machine key already)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are taking the viewstate that was returned from the server and updating your content page with it.  ViewState is basically an encoded set of name/value pairs that needs to match up with the content on the page that it's related to.  If you take the ViewState of one page and stick it on another, the encrypted value won't match up and you'll get an error that's similar to what you're seeing.

Since you're using jQuery and AJAX to dynamically get content from your server, I'm not sure why you're depending on ViewState (but I'm not familiar with your application).

Comment: Yes, it was dumb to use viewstate from one page on another. I've refactored code so that I use the same page. I have inherited this application, and it will be rewritten to use only ajax/jquery without postbacks but I has to work until then :)

Comment: Ahh, the inherited application.  My condolences.  :)  Good luck with the rewrite -- sounds like you're on the right path!!

Comment: -1 @DavidHoerster ViewState is not encrypted at all unless you explicitly tell asp.net that you want to encrypt it. Encoding != Encryption.

Comment: @DavidHoerster +1 now :) Much better!

Comment: @Icarus  Thanks.  I need to make a mental note about that.  I find myself switching those terms every now and then, and they are clearly not synonyms.  Thanks for keeping me honest!

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't go this route (updating the ViewState manually) as this is not an easy task; at the very least, ViewState is a BASE64 encoded string and you'll have to write quite a good deal of javascript code to always keep things in sync. I see this becoming a nightmare to maintain. In your shoes, I would be using strictly ajax instead allowing post backs like this or let MS handle ViewState for you, and use UpdatePanels but I dislike those too.

Further, if your app for some reason, ever needs to encrypt ViewState, you'll not be having fun maintaining your app.

Answer (score 1):

The encoded __VIEWSTATE is specific to the page that generated it. You will get a viewstate validation error if the page that your form posts to does not match the page that generated the viewstate. You have two options:

1. Send your AJAX request to the *same* page, not a different page.
2. Set the post URL of the form to the URL of the other page.